# Choice transport method for Socket IO

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have a web app that uses socket.io. Connecting the client to the server can take upwards of 12 seconds, and I'd like to cut that down. My research suggests that the delay is caused by socket io trying different transport methods and waiting for each to time out before trying the next method on the list. Is there anyway change that order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/learnboost/socket.io/#server-side-7

But I could not tell you which one take more time to responds. I've not play enough with those.

Comment: Thanks a bunch this was exactly what I needed. Connection time dropped from ~10 seconds to >1 second.